# How to open sticky notes with Process class?

Tags: c#

I want to open windows sticky notes with process class, I already know how to do this for calculator and paint but not sticky notes. when i give it the sticky note address it doesn't open. i use a 64-bit windows. (windows form)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace main
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mspaint");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc");
            //sticky notes
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\StikyNot.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

it gives the exception the file can not be found, but it exist in that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open the file from `C:\Windows\Sysnative\StikyNot.exe`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Sysnative\StikyNot.exe");
```

Since the `System32` folder on x64 systems is synthesized, calling it directly doesn't work. You have to use the `Sysnative` name to map the path to the 'real' system32 folder.

Comment: error the system cannot find file specified. i have win 8.1 64 bit

Comment: Open a Sticky Note, open the task manager, access the details tab, search for StikyNot.exe, right-click it, select "Open file location". Checking the location can't hurt.

Comment: I'm having the same as Riddle: StikyNot.exe is found in System32 and works but can't be opened using `Process.Start`.

Answer (score 1):

this location works for me on win 8.1 64 bit

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-stickynotes-app_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_de0517088d429664\StikyNot.exe");
```

if it didn't work for you, you can search for in your windows drive for other location of StikyNot

Comment: This works here as well. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't work in `System32` but it does here? Apparently the WinSxS folder is a folder that keeps installation files, but since it's also in System32 I'd expect it to work there too.

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't work in system32, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play around furthermore, you can use the below program as reference. It seemed to be a really good one.

Here is a sample invocation. Implementation logic is given below.

```
public void NewNote(string someText)
{
var note = new StickyNote();
note.Activate();
note.Activated += (s, e) => { note.Signal(someText); };
}
```

Credit goes to [Jesper Neidermann's Blog](http://www.niedermann.dk/2009/11/13/APIForStickyNotesInWindows7.aspx)

```
using System;  
using System.Diagnostics;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
using System.Threading;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  

namespace DayView  
{  
    public class StickyNote  
    {  
        private const string m_ProcessName = "StikyNot";  
        private readonly string m_ProcessFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "StikyNot.exe");  
        private event EventHandler m_Activated = delegate { };  
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]  
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]  
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);  

        public void Activate()  
        {  
            bool makeNewNote = true;  
            Process p = FindProcess();  
            if (p == null)  
            {  
                p = StartProcess();  
                if (!NoteContainsText(p.MainWindowHandle))  
                {  
                    makeNewNote = false;  
                }  
            }  
            var state = new StickyNoteState();  
            state.MakeNewNote = makeNewNote;  
            state.StickyNoteProcess = p;  
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Activate, state);  
        }  

        private void Activate(object state)  
        {  
            var stickyNoteState = state as StickyNoteState;  
            if (stickyNoteState.MakeNewNote)  
            {  
                NewNote(stickyNoteState.StickyNoteProcess);  
            }  
            OnActivated();  
        }  

        private Process StartProcess()  
        {  
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(m_ProcessFileName);  
            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);  
            Thread.Sleep(200); //This is an annoying hack. I haven't been able to find another way to be sure the process is started.  
            return p;  
        }  

        private void NewNote(Process p)  
        {  
            SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);  
            Signal("^n");              
        }  

        /// <summary>  
        /// Weird hack to find out if note contains text.  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <returns></returns>  
        private bool NoteContainsText(IntPtr handle)  
        {  
            string textOfClipboard = Clipboard.GetText();  
            Signal("^a");  
            Signal("^c");  
            Signal("{RIGHT}");  
            string noteText = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();  
            if (textOfClipboard == null)  
            {  
                Clipboard.SetText(textOfClipboard);  
            }  
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(noteText);  
        }  

        private Process FindProcess()  
        {  
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(m_ProcessName);  
                if(processes != null && processes.Length > 0)  
                {  
                    return processes[0];  
                }  
            return null;  
        }  

        internal void OnActivated()  
        {  
            m_Activated(this, new EventArgs());  
        }  

        public event EventHandler Activated  
        {  
            add { m_Activated += value; }  
            remove { m_Activated -= value; }  
        }  

        public void Signal(string message)  
        {  
            SendKeys.SendWait(message);  
            SendKeys.Flush();  
        }  
    }  

    public class StickyNoteState  
    {  
        public bool MakeNewNote { get; set; }  
        public Process StickyNoteProcess { get; set; }  

    }  
}
```

You need to add an app setting entry as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<configuration>  
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>  
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```